# Kotlin : How to Store Array List Object in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I create an android app with Kotlin which I created a data class "ProductQuantityData" which contains two attributes :"Quantity":Int and "Product":ProductData which product is a DataClass. I want to Store and get in sharedPreferences an arrayList of type "ProductQuantityData".Here's my code :

```
  private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences =
            context.getSharedPreferences(context.packageName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
       fun getProductInArrayListWithQuantities(key: String): ArrayList<ProductQuantityData> {
                val emptyList = Gson().toJson(ArrayList<ProductQuantityData>())
                return Gson().fromJson(
                    sharedPreferences.getString(key, emptyList),
                    object : TypeToken<ArrayList<ProductQuantityData>>() {}.type

                )
            }

        fun setProductInArrayListWithQuantities(DataArrayList:ArrayList<ProductQuantityData>, key: String) {
            val jsonString = Gson().toJson(DataArrayList)
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString(key, jsonString).apply()
        }
```

I get the following error :

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.app.honey, PID: 18325
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.honey/com.app.honey.activity.product.ProductDetail}:
>   com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 3 path $[0]
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78).......

I know that the problem is here `sharedPreferences.getString(key, emptyList)`,because the type is not String, is an object.
So, How can I correct my code to make it work.
I just change getProductInArrayListWithQuantities to the following code and my problem is solved :

```
fun getProductInArrayListWithQuantities(key: String): ArrayList<ProductQuantityData> {
    var prodQte: ArrayList<ProductQuantityData>
    val json = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "")
    prodQte = if (json!!.isEmpty()) {
        ArrayList()
    } else {
        val type = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<ProductQuantityData>>() {
        }.type
        Gson().fromJson<ArrayList<ProductQuantityData>>(json, type)
    }
    return prodQte
}
```

Comment: Error log says everything. Your JSON is not correct.

Comment: Yes, I Know but How can I correct it ?

Comment: Add your JSON in question

Comment: The json format probably should be [{"productName": "XYZ", "quantity": 1}]

Comment: I found a solution, I update my post